# Open Extension page at fixed Position attached to chrome on Extension Icon on event of click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I have a requirement in creating a extension.
I need to create a extension screen fixed Position to chrome at top at event of click or hover.
but I don't know any that kind of api.

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.extension.getURL('landing.html'), active: true }, function(tab) { chrome.windows.create({ tabId: tab.id, type: 'popup', 'width': w, 'height': h, 'left': left, 'top': top, focused: true }); });
```

and type is `type: 'popup'` OR `type: 'normal'` OR `type: 'devtools'`
but in any case I am not able to achieve what i needed.
what I am doing wrong ?
Or there is no API For that in chrome.
I need this kind of behavior from chrome.

[image]

Comment: There's no API to move the browserAction/pageAction popup. You can use chrome.windows.create to make a new small window. Or you can insert a DOM element into the current page that looks like a modal. Or you can write a [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) host utility that uses low-level OS methods to move the standard extension popup.

Answer (score 0):

The popup of a [browserAction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction) is placed at the top of the page, just below the action button in the navigationbar (like in the screenshot of yours).
The dimensions (but not the position) can be set using a stylesheet for the HTML you supply for this popup.

manifest.json:

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "The tooltip of the action button",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "32": "icon32.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "your_popup.html",
    "browser_style": true
  }
```

Comment: Yes did this thing already.I want fixed pop up attached to the Extension Icon

Comment: That should be the case for browser action popups. Or what exactly is different to what you want to achieve?

Comment: can you see any cross button on the right side of the pop up I want a fixed floating window which is attached to my extension icon after click outside of the pop up it should disable itself. and user can enable it by left click on extension icon,Or click on context menu icon on right click.